# What is the '@' symbol called in the XNA framework enum for keys?

Tags: c#, input, xna, key

In my game, I check for input of keys using the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input library, for example, Keys.A is A, or Keys.OemTilde is '~', but I cannot find the right key for @ in the enum called Keys. Can someone tell me what it is?

Answer (score 0):

On US Keyboards it is: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>

So the full code example is:

```
KeyboardState ks = Keyboard.GetState();
if((ks.isKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift) || ks.isKeyDown(Keys.RightShift)) && ks.isKeyDown(Keys.D2))
{
    // @ was pressed
}
```

Please see the `Keys` Enum [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.key?view=netframework-4.7.2) for all of the keys.

Not all keyboard layouts are the same.

A simple way to figure out what key is pressed is to add the following code to `game1.cs`:

```
// Class level variables
KeyboardState ks = new KeyboardState(),oks;
```

Then in the `Update` method:

```
oks = ks;
ks = KeyBoard.GetState();

Keys[] pressed = new Keys[0];
if(ks != oks)
{
   // A key was pressed
   pressed = ks.GetPressedKeys();
}
foreach(var key in pressed)
   Console.WriteLine(key.ToString());
```

Do not use any modifiers(<kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>) When running this code, or you will end up with a lot of `LeftShift` lines on your output.

View the Output tab in Visual Studio to see the keys pressed.

Remove these lines after testing.